# High CPU and RAM usage, how to know what is the cause?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, server

I am maintaining a cloud server (ubuntu 14, webuzo) on Amazon (AWS).
Recently the usage of CPU and RAM are increasing high which cause the server going down.

i thought there is an attact to the server, then i try to modify the security from the AWS console. I block all the ports, except for accessing the control panel of my hosting panel which i set it to only accept from my ip address.

But still, the CPU and RAM usage is still high.

I guess this is not caused from the outside(attact/flood), but it comes from inside the server.

So the question is how to know or determine what is the cause?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the processess using more memmory using `top` or `htop`

```
top -o %MEM -o %CPU
```

here you can get a visual repersentation of what is going on in your server then you can stop the service

```
service <service name> restart
```

or process by

```
kill -9 <process id>
```

You can also clear the cache by

```
sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Comment: Thanks Jobin. Your solution should be the one i need..

Answer (score 2):

You can check which Process is taking up the CPU and RAM, by this command

```
ps -eo pid cmd %mem %cpu
```

If the process is not useful to you right now, Kill the process with -

```
kill <pid>
```

or forcefully kill by-

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

Comment: i got this error: unsupported option (BSD syntax). what could be the problem? thanks

Comment: `ps` options are not portable, yours probably wants sightly different ones. The answer shoud arguably explain what the options do.

Answer (score 0):

Use `top` and see whats taking your CPU and RAM if not critical kill unnecessary process, with `kill <pid>` or `kill -9 <pid>`